# How to show the isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I'm not sure how to show this

$$\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(x^3 -x +1)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(x^3 -x^2+x +1).$$

Any help or hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two polynomials are irreducible (no roots, small degree) you simply need to invoke the uniqueness of finite fields of a given order:  Finite field extensions are uniquely characterized by their order. Since both of them are finite fields of order $3^3=27$ they are isomorphic, and in fact are exactly the set of all solutions to $x^{27}-x=0$.

---

If you're not aware of this, then we can prove it:

Let $F$ be a field with $27$ elements. Then since $F^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $26$, we have, by LaGrange's theorem, that $x^{26}-1$ is satisfied by all non-zero elements of $F$, and so $x^{27}-x$ is satisfied by all elements of $F$.

Hence $F$ is isomorphic to the splitting field for $x^{27}-x$ over $\Bbb F_3$, the field with three elements. Since isomorphism is an equivalence relation, any two fields of this order are isomorphic to one another.

Comment: So you are saying arbitrary fields of order $p^n$ are isomorphic to each other when $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: @Topoguy yes, this is accurate. If you're interested in the details, it's basically exactly the same proof I just wrote, only with numbers changed to symbols. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness has some details

Comment: In fact, finite fields are isomorphic iff they have the same cardinality.

Comment: neat and clean approach.Can you suggest some books on finite fields.thanks it would be great if you do so@AdamHughes

Comment: @learnmore finite fields are pretty straightforward, most good basic number theory or field theory books will go through things related to them. If you want some with exercises, I'd recommend Dummit and Foote. If you want a *very* modern approach which builds everything up from the absolute ground in a very high-tech way, I'd say André Weil's *Basic Number Theory* is my favorite account.

Comment: thank you sir one more question how did you conclude from Lagranges theorem the statement you wrote.It only says order of a subgroup  divides order of group@AdamHughes

Comment: @learnmore This implies that the order of any element divides the order of the group, i.e. any element $x\in G$ satisfies $x^{|G|}=e_G$

Comment: yes right thank you very very much @AdamHughes

Answer (score 3):

First, observe that each of the polynomials $x^3-x+1$ and $x^3-x^2+x+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$. To prove this, we use the following fact.

**If $\deg p\leq 3$ and $p$ has no roots, then $p$ is irreducible**

**Proof:**

If $p$ was reducible, there would be non-constant polynomials $f,g$ such that $p=fg$. Then by degree considerations, we have either $\deg f\leq 1$ or $\deg g\leq 1$. Consequently we have found a root of $p$, which is a contradiction. $\square$

Now by plugging in 0,1,2 into the polynomials, we see that neither has a root over $\mathbb Z_3$. Thus each defines a degree 3 extension of $\mathbb Z_3$. Recall that $\mathbb Z_3$ is the field of order 3; therefore each extension defines the field of order 27. Hence they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing wrong with the other answers. But if you want a **concrete** isomorphism you can find one (in this case) with the following ad hoc trick.

Let $\beta$ be a zero of the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x^2+x+1$. Then
$$
(\beta+1)^3-(\beta+1)^2=(\beta^3+1)-(\beta^2+2\beta+1)=p(\beta)-1=-1.
$$
So
$$
(\beta+1)^3-(\beta+1)^2+1=0.
$$
Dividing this equation by $(\beta+1)^3$ gives
$$
1-\frac1{\beta+1}+\frac1{(\beta+1)^3}=0.
$$
This means that $\alpha=1/(\beta+1)$ is a zero of the polynomial $q(x)=x^3-x+1$.

Your former field $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3[\alpha]$ by the standard argument. Similar your second field
$\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3[\beta]$. An isomorphism
is thus given by extending $\alpha\mapsto 1/(\beta+1)$.

---

How did I find this? In characteristic three you cannot make the quadratic term of a cubic vanish of $p(x)$ by a linear substitution. Therefore I wanted to make the linear term vanish instead. Then I "went reciprocal" and instead of looking for $q(x)$ I looked for its reciprocal polynomial $x^3q(1/x)$. This time I was lucky. I could have also tried replacing $\alpha$ or $\beta$ with its negative. I don't know, if it's worth your while to learn all these tricks, but they do make an appearance every now and then.

Comment: For $(\beta+1)^3-(\beta+1)^2=(\beta^3+1)-(\beta^2+2\beta+1)=p(\beta)-1=-1$. I can't see why. Since you're calculating under $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x]$, it seems $(\beta+1)^3-(\beta+1)^2=(\beta^3+1)-(\beta^2+2\beta+1)=\beta^3-\beta^2+\beta$

Comment: Sorry, I saw it.